# Downloaded IPA to Windows 8...now what? Can I upload to itunes from Windows or do I I need a mac?

Tags: windows, cordova, openssl, app-store-connect

I have Windows 8.  I built and Android application in Eclipse, translated it through Cordova then zipped it and uploaded to phonegap build.  I got an Apple provisioning certificate using OpenSSL.  I set up my app(icon, pics, description) in iTunes connect which tells me my app is ready for upload.  I downloaded the IPA from phonegap.  Now what?  Do I have to upload the IPA (file downloaded from phonegap) to Itunes via a mac?  Itunes wants me to download Application Loader.  However, this is only available for mac.  So...what do I have to do to get my app on itunes?

Comment: so, in fact, phonegap does not eliminate the need for a mac, it eliminates the need to use more than one SDK.  And by extension, the need to learn more than one OOP language.

Comment: What you can do without a mac is install the app on a device of a specific uuid, but you need a mac to add your app on the store.